# System.getProperty("user.home") doesnt work

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

doesnt show anything but

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

shows `/`

I expect something like `C:/user/path`

Comment: According to Oracle docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html, "user.home" should work unless you're on weird Windows... are you? Try to see if there's anything good in system environment https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html

Comment: Are you trying to get this property in a Android app?

Comment: Yeap, ım using android studio